# What all things do one needs to consider when UI scripts needs to support same application in different language

Tags: automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

We have developed few UI automation scripts using Microsoft UIA for automating application developed in wpf. Currently our dev team  is working on to support French language and making necessary modifications in application. In scripts we have used all of our controls either by name or ID property and hoping that it would not fail on different locale.

Still wish to start this thread to understand what all things one needs to consider while moving automation scripts for supporting one locale to other.

Many thanks in advance!